# How to send String obtained from Spinner between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast

So I have 2 activities, I want to pass a string obtained from a spinner when when an item is selected from my 2nd activity to the 1st one.

2nd activity :

```js
filetypeselected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                                                                   Intent filetypeselectedintent = new Intent(advancedoptionsactivity.this,First.class);
                                                                    filetypeselectedintent.putExtra("filetypeselected", filetypeselected);
                                                                    startActivity(filetypeselectedintent);
```

1st activity:

Under onResume:

```js
        String filetypeselected =null;
        Intent filetypeselectedintent = this.getIntent();

        if(filetypeselectedintent != null)
        {
            filetypeselected = filetypeselectedintent.getStringExtra("filetypeselected");
        }

        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setText(filetypeselected);
```

However when an item is selected from spinner in the 2nd activity, the 1st activity comes up instead... What I wanted to have is once the item is selected in the spinner of 2nd activity, the intent is sent to activity 1 while the activity 2 remains on my screen...

I was thinking of using broadcasters, if I;m supposed to use one, could someone tell me how to register the receiver in activity 1 ?

Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

Here is the code with the Shared Preference :
First activity :
 under onResume()

```js
            SharedPreferences AdvancedOptions = getSharedPreferences("AdvancedOptions",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            filetypeselected = AdvancedOptions.getString(filetypeselected, null);

            TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
            test.setText(String.valueOf(filetypeselected));
```

Second Activity :

Under onchecklistener

```js
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

                    {
                    if (position != 0)
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " has been selected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        filetypeselected = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

                            SharedPreferences AdvancedOptions = getSharedPreferences("AdvancedOptions",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor AdvancedOptionsEditor = AdvancedOptions.edit();
                            AdvancedOptionsEditor.putLong("filetypeselected",filetypeselected);
                            AdvancedOptionsEditor.commit();


                        }
                    }
```

Maybe it has something to do with the variable instantiation of filetypeselected ?

in First Activity under

```js
public class First extends Activity {

    String filetypeselected =null;

[...]
```

and in the Second Activity

```js
public class advancedoptionsactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Long filetypeselected;
  [...]
```

The issue is TextView test (in the first activity) is always stuck on the text : "null" when it's supposed to show the id of the item selected in the spinner (2nd activity).

Comment: for achieving that you will have to use shared preferences. startActivity means start another activity. Intent does not work without starting another component whether it returns a result or not

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am now reading a tutorial on shared preferences. I will get back to you on how things go !

Comment: @Aakash hey, I have update the first post... I am trying to use shared preference but it's not working properly, i'm going to read up about preference manager now since that's what people are talking about

Comment: The line `filetypeselected = AdvancedOptions.getString(filetypeselected, null);` makes no sence. You have to get the string by its name. Right now you are using an empty variable as name, which always returns null. Also i recommend you follow Javas naming conventions.

Comment: Passing information like that does work, but if it were up to me i would say its bad design that you have to do this. I don't know how it looks in your case, but what you are trying to do might be solved by `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: do you mean 
filetypeselected = AdvancedOptions.getString("filetypeselected", null);  

?

I don't follow...

Comment: the 2nd activity is started like this :
`public void advancedoptions (View view)
    {
        Intent startadvancedoptionsactivity = new Intent(this,advancedoptionsactivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(startadvancedoptionsactivity,1);
    }`

Comment: Yes thats what i mean. When it comes to the whole activity to activity talking in your case, i can't tell because it a design question and i cant really help without the whole idea of what you are doing. And i think its too broad of a question for stack overflow. To learn good practices in Android programming with little experience of java i recommend the book "Android Programming:The Big Nerd Ranch Guide 2nd Edition".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a simple callback interface. Let the first activity implement:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements SecondActivity.Callback{
    private String fileTypeSelected;
    ...
    @Override 
    public void doStuff(String stuff){
        if(stuff!= null)
        {
            this.fileTypeSelected= stuff;
        }
    }
    @Override 
    public void onResume(){
        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setText(filetypeselected);
    }
```

}

Then in the 2nd Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
    public interface Callback{
        void doStuff(String stuff);
    }
    private Callback callback; //get reference to FirstActivity somehow
    ...
}
```

Then in 2nd Activity you just call:

```
callback.doStuff(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

The first activity will get the stuff it needs, and when you come back to it, it will update its views.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you know both activities aren't instantiated at the same time, you can save the information in `Shared Preferences` in `SecondActivity` and then retrieve the information in `FirstActivity`'s `onResume()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am now reading a tutorial on shared preferences. I will get back to you on how things go !

Comment: I used shared preferences but I have been getting some issues (not with the compiler, no errors during compile). I have updated the main post, tell me what you think

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem

Comment: "The issue is TextView test (in the first activity) is always stuck on the text : "null" when it's supposed to show the id of the item selected in the spinner (2nd activity)." ^^